# Vertically aligning radio buttons in center aligned text

Tags: css

I have some text with radio buttons. I center aligned it via `<div style="text-align:center;">`. It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can vertically align all the radio buttons *while ensuring the whole thing remains center aligne*d?

I tried wrapping the radio buttons separately in `<div style="text-align:left;">` but that doesn't give the desired results I need.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample, including your markup and CSS?

Comment: Please provide your code so that it will be easy to identify where it went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to centre the div and then align your radios to that div so:

```css
#main {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#radioDiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/>

  <div id="radioDiv">
    <br/><input type="radio" name="example" value="x">x
    <br/><input type="radio" name="example" value="xx">xx
    <br/><input type="radio" name="example" value="xxx">xxx
  </div>
</div>
```

The jsfiddle here should [help](https://jsfiddle.net/qj7yL4bm/).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>

<div style="margin: auto;width:500px;height: 100px;">
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```